# Adding a record from selected table row

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I have a wrapper class which updates selected rows from the standard object **orderItem**, with details from a custom object called **Delivery_Note__c**.

A change in requirements has meant that I have had to create a junction object between the two objects called **Delivery_Note_Line_Item**.

I would like to update the wrapper to create a new **Delivery_Note_Line_Item** against every selected orderItem, populating both the orderItem, and the Delivery_Note__c lookups, as well as a quantity field.

I am not sure how to go about inserting the new record, using the current wrapper class.

Class:

```
public with sharing class DeliveryNoteSelectExtension {

    public String redirectUrl {get;set;} 

    public List<wrapOrderItem> wrapOrderItemList {get; set;}
    public List<OrderItem> selectedOrderItems {get;set;}

    public Delivery_Note__c currentRecord {get;set;}

    public DeliveryNoteSelectExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        currentRecord = [SELECT id,name,order__c,Order__r.id FROM Delivery_Note__c WHERE id = :ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('ID')];
        redirectUrl = '/'+currentRecord.Id;

        if(wrapOrderItemList == null) {
            wrapOrderItemList = new List<wrapOrderItem>();
            for(OrderItem o: [
                SELECT id,
                    Delivery_Note__c,Delivered__c,Delivery_Note__r.name,Delivery_Note__r.id,ListPrice,Product2.name,Product2.ProductCode,Quantity,
                    Quantity_Picked__c,Quantity_Back_Order__c,TotalPrice,Total_GST__c,Total_Including_GST__c
                FROM orderItem 
                WHERE orderid = :currentRecord.order__r.id 
                AND Quantity_Back_Order__c > 0

            ]){
                wrapOrderItemList.add(new wrapOrderItem(o));
            }
        }
    }

    public void processSelected() {
        selectedOrderItems = new List<orderItem>();

        for(wrapOrderItem wrapOrderItemObj : wrapOrderItemList) {
            if(wrapOrderItemObj.selected == true) {
                selectedOrderItems.add(wrapOrderItemObj.oi);
                wrapOrderItemObj.oi.Delivery_Note__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
                wrapOrderItemObj.oi.delivered__c = TRUE;
            }

        }
        update selectedOrderItems;
    }

    public class wrapOrderItem {
        public orderItem oi {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}

        public wrapOrderItem(orderItem o) {
            oi = o;
            selected = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Hey Santanu, I am stuck with where/how to insert the new record, using the wrapper (selected items)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it' seems easy to me,

```
public void processSelected() {
selectedOrderItems = new List<orderItem>();
List<Delivery_Note_Line_Item__c> delNoteLineItemsTobeInserted = new List<Delivery_Note_Line_Item__c>();
for(wrapOrderItem wrapOrderItemObj : wrapOrderItemList) {
    if(wrapOrderItemObj.selected == true) {
        selectedOrderItems.add(wrapOrderItemObj.oi);
        wrapOrderItemObj.oi.Delivery_Note__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        wrapOrderItemObj.oi.delivered__c = TRUE;

        Delivery_Note_Line_Item__c newDelItem = new Delivery_Note_Line_Item__c();
        newDelItem.OrderLineItemLookup__c = wrapOrderItemObj.oi.Id;
        newDelItem.Delivery_Note__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        delNoteLineItemsTobeInserted.add(newDelItem);
    }

}
if(delNoteLineItemsTobeInserted.size() > 0){
    insert delNoteLineItemsTobeInserted;
}
update selectedOrderItems;
}
```

Hope This helps !!